# JAVA A list of objects with another list to Map

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

Given a class Object1

```
class Object1 {
 private Object2 object2;
 private List<Object3> object3s;
}
```

and a `List<Object1>`

cuurent implementation

```
Map<Object3, Object2> accountMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Object1 dto : accounts) {
            dto.getObject3s()
                    .forEach(dto -> accountMap.put(dto, dto.getObject2()));
        }
```

How do I create a `Map<Object3, Object2>` preferably in a stream?

Answer (score 5):

I believe doing this in a stream would look something like this:

```
Map<Object3, Object2> map = list.stream()
     .flatMap(o1 -> o1.object3s.stream().map(o3 -> Map.entry(o3, o1.object2)))
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

That is, flatmap your stream of `Object1` to a stream of entries of `Object3` and `Object2`; and then collect them to a map.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this with streams, you need an auxiliary object, that would hold references to `Object3` and `Object2`.

A good practice is to use a [Java 16 `record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) for that purpose, if you're using an earlier JDK version you can define a `class`. Sure a quick and dirty option `Map.Entry` will do as well, but it reduces the readability of code because methods `getKey()` and `getValue()` give no clue what they are returning, it would be even confusing if the source of the stream is entry set and there would be several kinds of entries in the pipeline.

Here's how such a record might look like:

```
public record Objects3And2(Object3 object3, Object2 object2) {}
```

In the stream, you need to flatten the data by creating a new instance of record `Objects3And2` for every nested `Object3`. For that, we can use either [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) of [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

And to accumulate the data into a map we can make use of the collector [`toMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function))

***Note** that in this implementation (as well as in your code) values of duplicated `Object3` would be *overridden*.*

```
List<Object1> accounts = // initializing the list

Map<Object3, Object2> accountMap = accounts.stream()
    .flatMap(o1 -> o1.getObject3s().stream()
        .map(o3 -> new Objects3And2(o3, o1.getObject2()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Objects3And2::object3, // generating a Key
        Objects3And2::object2, // generating a Value
        (l, r) -> r            // resolving Duplicates
    ));
```

If you don't want to lose the data, you need a different structure of the resulting map and different collector, namely [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) as its downstream.

```
List<Object1> accounts = // initializing the list

Map<Object3, List<Object2>> accountMap = accounts.stream()
    .flatMap(o1 -> o1.getObject3s().stream()
        .map(o3 -> new Objects3And2(o3, o1.getObject2()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Objects3And2::object3,
        Collectors.mapping(Objects3And2::object2,
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```